# SQL '>' showing up as '$gt;' in Python MySQL Connecor

Tags: python, mysql, rest

I am using MySQL connector to write a database connection API and I am having a problem when using relational statements. When I write ">" in the string and pass it in as the query string, I get this SQL error because it does not recognize ">"

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
        that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GHI_DATA.time_stamp &gt;=
        2019-5-10' at line 1 // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

Comment: How are you constructing and passing your query string?

Comment: How are you displaying this error?  My guess is that the > is fine, but the error is being returned through your web API and is being converted.  Perhaps you should show us the whole query.  Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything in the error message saying that the > caused the error, it's just saying that the error is near the line containing the >. Try writing simple queries with > and see whether just the > character is enough to cause an error. You should also post the code that's causing the error.